# Why Android app crash when close app if I getExtras in Service?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

In `Activity` I start a service

```
Intent serv=new Intent(this, MyService.class);
serv.putExtra("mac", "mac");
startService(serv);
```

In the service, I get the parameter

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    String mac=intent.getExtras().getString("mac");
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

Then I kill the app, the app will crash, and the service will also crash.

If I remove this line, then it will be no problem, the service also alive after I killed the app.

```
String mac=intent.getExtras().getString("mac");
```

Why the app crash?

Comment: Should probably edit the question with logcat output if you are looking for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)` returns the [`START_STICKY`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY) flag by default which, according to the docs, mean that:

*"if this service's process is killed while it is started (after returning from onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)), then leave it in the started state but don't retain this delivered intent."*

Since the `Intent` isn't being redelivered you likely get `NPE` when calling `intent.getExtras()`.

To redeliver the `Intent` return the [`START_REDELIVER_INTENT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_REDELIVER_INTENT) flag from `onStartCommand()`:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    ...
    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are putting extras to wrong intent `bleService.putExtra("mac", "mac");`

Instead you should write `serv.putExtra("mac", "mac");`

Also you should always check if there are extras

```
if(getIntent().hasExtra("mac"){
   //do some stuff
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that is my typo in question. Finally I found the problem, when I kill the app, the service will be restarted, then the intent will be null.